# How can one determine whether the backend of a reverse-proxied DNS record is correctly configured?

Tags: dns, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I am using 3rd-party services (namely, Short.cm and Rebrandly) for a custom-domain URL shortener. I connected a spare subdomain of mine to each of them, and turned on Cloudflare CDN (the orange cloud icon in Cloudflare dashboard). It works correctly that my subdomains are pointing to Cloudflare's IPs (two each from `104.16.0.0/12`), but I'm a bit surprised to learn that both services providers informed me that my domain was configured properly.

I tried on my own but couldn't find any way to find out the backend IP address for my domains except logging in to Cloudflare and retrieve it from the dashboard. How could those URL shortener service providers know that my domains are correctly set up?